# Use ssh key for remote java debugging using intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, ssh-keys

I want to do remote java debugging using Intellij by connecting to a running program on a remote machine.

However, I use an ssh key to access this remote machine and cannot find any place to specify this key in the remote configuration window. Any idea how this can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first create an ssh tunnel to the remote machine and then connect to the program just as if it was running on your own system.